# How to remove attributes from HTML using javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom

I have an HTML with say a textfield (input element).

```
<input name="capacity" type="text" value="blah blah blah">
```

This simply displays a text field on my page with a default value "blah blah blah".

What I want to do is remove value attribute, as I don't want to see this default value.
I am doing this using javascript.

```
value = element.getAttribute("value");
    if((element.readOnly != undefined || element.readOnly == false) || (element.disabled != undefined || element.disabled == false)){
    //element.removeAttribute(value);    
    element.removeAttribute("value");
```

But it is not working. I even tried

```
element.setAttribute("value","");
```

but no luck.
Any pointers where I may be missing.

---

**EDIT :**
I got an issue related to this question, anyone interested may [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7568343/dynamically-change-the-html-source-using-native-javascript)

*********************************************
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you considered using a placeholder attribute instead of a default value? Only works in modern browsers though.

Comment: @Chamika Already done that...See 3rd comment for alex's answer.Thanks for replying, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ...I don't want to see this default value.

Just set the `value` property directly to an empty string.

```
document.getElementsByName('capacity')[0].value = '';
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w7nZ7/).

Comment: by directly you mean, simply open the HTML into edit mode instead of browser and change the attribute manually.

Comment: @mohit That's now what I meant, but if you could do that, why bother with JavaScript at all? What outputs this form element?

Comment: It worked . I was too worked up with removeAttribute and setAttribute that I totally missed this simple friend of mine.  :)  Thanx alex.      I modified it a bit though. element.value=""; This way I don't need to care about id or name of my elements.

Comment: It seems that the values are not being changed permanently. I mean as I refresh the page it starts showing the old values again.Any idea what is going on ?

Comment: @mohit That's expected behaviour. HTTP is a stateless protocol by design.

Comment: well yes, but when I clean my web page this way I save that page locally on my hard disk.Shouldn't it save the changes made.

Answer (score 0):

Give your text field and id like `<input name="capacity" type="text" id="text" value="blah blah blah">` `document.getElementById['text'].value = "";`

Answer (score 0):

**This is your html tag. You will need to add a ID to it**

```
<input id="capacity" name="capacity" type="text" value="blah blah blah">
```

**This is just to fire the javascript function**

```
<input type="submit" value="Click" onclick="javascript:return reset();" />
```

**The following function will reset the value of the selected element**

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function reset() {
        document.getElementById("capacity").value = "";
        return false; // In order to avoid postback
    }   
</script>
```

If you are not using form and you want to use it with just the name you can try the following

```
 this.capacity.value = '';
```

Comment: +1 for very nicely written answer but capacity is not id, it is name.Will your code work ?

Comment: It's pretty awful really. The language attribute was deprecated over a decade ago, there is no need for "javascript:" in the handler, it is treated as a useless label, returning false from the submit button's click handler will not stop a form submitting. Don't use a submit button if you don't want it to submit the form (change the type to button), etc. The handler could be: `this.form.capacity.value = '';`

Comment: Thanks buddy :-), will remember that